# Under Chrome - Mootools inject fails with null element

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, mootools

I have this weird problem on Chrome - on my page I am injecting elements using Mootools specifically a lightbox that contains a jwplayer video. The problem on chrome is that referring to an element ie. $('grid_01'); returns null the second time I click on it. To get around this I'm trying to test the element is null and re-inject it

```
            var ss = $('holderdiv');
            var x = $('mb_inline_0_-1');
            if(x == null)
            {
                var el = new Element("div", {id: "mb_inline_0_-1"});
            //if this line below runs without error...
                ss.inject(el);

            }
            //.........why would x2 be null?

             var x2 = $('mb_inline_0_-1');
```

Chrome says its null. Is there something I can do to ensure the DOM is updated ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mean to use grab, not inject.

```
ss.grab(el);  // Or el.inject(ss);
```

Your code has ss being injected into el, which is never attached to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Injecting a newly created `Element` is written in the format `newElement.inject(existingElement, position);`.

So in your case, if you are planning to inject the newly created `div` (contained in `el`) into `$('holderdiv')`, it should be done thusly:

```
var el = new Element('div', {
    . . .
});
el.inject('holderdiv', 'bottom');    // Although 'bottom' is assumed if nothing is passed
```